# mysql update with condition

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table with 3 columns - key, valid and admin. I want to update the valid column of three rows - key IN (1,2,3). Now, I want to update it to 1 for all of them except the ones that have admin = 1. I thought something like this (not correct, just to show what I would like):

```
UPDATE table SET valid = 1
WHERE key IN (1,2,3)
AND key NOT IN(
 SELECT key from table
 WHERE admin = 1
)
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink the problem.

```
update
  table
set
  valid = 1
where
  key in (1,2,3)
  and admin != 1
```